# Hacking my knitting machine - No module named image

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, module, python-imaging-library

I'm working on this tutorial

https://learn.adafruit.com/electroknit/insert

to hack my knitting machine and I'm hitting a wall. When I get to the insert pattern step I type in this command:

```
python insertpattern.py IMG PatternNumber BMPfile
```

I keep getting the same error:

```
File "insertpattern.py", line 22, in <module>
import Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

I've installed Pillow because PIL is no longer current but that didn't do anything. Is there another way to install an image module for Python 2.7 that will allow me to make this command work?

Comment: Post your code.  It sounds like you're trying to import a module named `Image`, but it isn't installed.

Comment: `C:\Users\ktyle\OneDrive\Desktop\KnitKing>python insertpattern.py  img/00.dat 901 fuckall.bmp myfile.dat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "insertpattern.py", line 22, in <module>
    import Image
ImportError: No module named Image`
 
sorry very new to stack, the formatting isn't great. But I've used the pip commands to install PIL, Pillow, and Image and I still get this error every single time.